# Express: How to return a 404 if object does not exist in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have the following code where if the correct `req.path` is defined, it returns some text. I need to display a 404 not found.

If I place it in the for loop conditional, it will return a bunch of `not found` by using `break;` it somewhat works.

My pseudocode is roughly like this: if Obj exists print it, else show a 404 page.

In this case where should I place `res.send(404)` ?

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome!")
})


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  jsonfile.readFile(file, (err, obj) => {
    let pokedex = obj.pokemon
    let result = []
    let format = req.path.split('/');
    let userPath = format[1]

    for (var i = 0; i < pokedex.length; i++) {
      if (userPath == pokedex[i].name.toLowerCase()) {
        result.push(
          "<h1>" + pokedex[i].name + "</h1><ul>Weight: " + pokedex[i].weight + "</ul>" );
      }
    }
    res.send(result.join())
  })
})
```

Comment: You mean if the path is not correct or not find in that case you want to return 404?

Comment: is this an ajax request or you need server side rendering? In case of ajax, you ll need to handle this on client side too

Comment: @ManjeetThakur yeap if my req.path doesn't match anything in the JSON it should return a 404. I tried using else but it throws me an error.

Comment: @scetiner purely server side rendering.

Comment: can you paste error here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before `res.send(result.join())` do :

```
if(result.length < 1) {
  res.send(404);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Gah I totally forgot that I needed to check that. I've been trying to put res.send("404") everywhere. Cheers!